# Can we use Laravel Form Binding without Eloquent ORM?

Tags: php, model, laravel, laravel-4

I am not using `Eloquent ORM` for Laravel 4 and willing to bind my Model with Edit Form using `model binding`. My code is given below:

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('exchanges', 'Exchange@index');
//Route::get('details/{exchangeID}', 'Exchange@details');

//add question to make the parameter option
Route::get('details/{exchangeID?}', function($exchangeID = 0)
{
    return App::make('Exchange')->details($exchangeID);
});

//Admin Dashboard
Route::get('admin', 'Exchange@dashboard');
//Route::get('admin/exchange/edit/{exchangeID?}', function($exchangeID = 0)
//{
//    return App::make('Exchange')->edit($exchangeID);
//});
Route::model('exchange', 'ExchangeModel');
Route::get('admin/exchange/edit/{exchange}', array('uses' => 'Exchange@edit', 'as' => 'exchange.edit'));
```

**Controller Method**

```
public function edit(ExchangeModel $exchange)
    {
             return View::make('exchangeedit')->with('exchange', $exchange);
```

**VIew**

```
{{ Form::model($exchange, array('route' => array('exchange.edit', $exchange->id))) }}
        {{ Form::close() }}
```

**Model**

```
public static function all()
    {
        return DB::select('select * from Exchanges');
    }
```

However When I visit: `http://localhost/path/site/public/admin/exchange/edit/4` It considers  it a 404 and redirects to a 404 page. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @Sheikh Heera for sake of clarity, can you add it as a separate answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 404 error is being generated by your **Route model binding** `Route::model()`. If you are not using Eloquent, route model binding won't function as expected without additional work (mainly making sure your desired class has a `find()` method, which will return the record you need).

You do not need to use route model binding in order to use **Form model binding**. These are two different features, neither of which depend on the either.

Form model binding does NOT require an Eloquent model instance. It can be any array or object with the correct properties / keys. Here's an excerpt from `Illuminate\Html\FormBuilder.php` that is responsible for finding a model attribute:

```
protected function getModelValueAttribute($name)
{
    if (is_object($this->model))
    {
        return object_get($this->model, $this->transformKey($name));
    }
    elseif (is_array($this->model))
    {
        return array_get($this->model, $this->transformKey($name));
    }
}
```

`object_get()` and `array_get()` are Laravel [helper functions](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers), if you want to look into them further.

So you do not need an Eloquent model to use **form** model binding, but you will probably want to use it when using **route** model binding. :)

Comment: where in routing I am making mistake?? Is there some way to debug it?

Comment: Remove your call to `Route::model()`. If you aren't using Eloquent for your `ExchangeModel` class, it will likely continue to error unless you work around it properly. Like I said, you do not need route model binding in order to use form model binding. They are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use a model binding without `Eloquent ORM` because in `Route::model()` method there is something like this

```
if ($model = with(new $class)->find($value))
{
    return $model;
}
```

So, when you use following code to bind a model

```
Route::model('exchange', 'ExchangeModel');
```

The `model` method of the `router` class does something like this

```
$model = new $class; // Here $class is your ExchangeModel
$model->find(($value) // The id passed to the url {exchange}
if($model) return $model;
```

So, when you are not extending the `Eloquent ORM` in your model there is no such method like `find` is available because `Eloquent` is an alias of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class and `find` method belongs to this `Model` class.

**Update :** As an alternative, you may try something like this. Add a `find` method in your model like this

```
class Exchange {
    public static function find($id)
    {
        $user = DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->get();
        if($user) {
            $user = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection($user);
            return $user->first();
        }
        return false; // or not found exception
     }
}
```

This way, you can still use `Form::model()` in your form. If you don't want use `static` method you can change it but can't use `::` method call.

BTW, you may also use something like this (can manually pass the model to the form)

```
public function edit($id)
{
     // Manually load the model and pass to view
     $exchange = Exchange::find($id);
     return View::make('exchangeedit')->with('exchange', $exchange);
}
```

So, in this case your route should be normally (without model binding)

```
Route::get('admin/exchange/edit/{exchange}', ['uses' => 'Exchange@edit', 'as' => 'exchange.edit']);
```

Comment: how about adding a find() method? this is what I did but then route went to some other world. Actually I want to bind because I want preFilled form with value. Guess I need to do it manually?

Comment: I often use `Form::model()` without model binding, just gave the example in my answer.

Comment: Hey @Volatil3, I've updated the answer, I do it on `Eloquent` models but didn't try on any normal model.

Comment: Your `class Exchange` with this find method and you can use the same route binding with this method added because it returns `Eloquent` model.

Comment: @Volatil3, just add the `find` method in your `Exchange` model (I've provided in the updated answer, in `Exchange model`) and you are done. You can use same model binding in route and `form::model` in your view.